# Cloud9 ide: how running php tests in debug?

Tags: php, debugging, cloud9-ide

Hi I'm pretty new in PHP (btw experienced with C#) and trying to debug a PHP project in the Cloud9 Online editor. I'running my PHP file through the "PHP build-in server", but I can not figure out what the url is, through which I can see my application in the browser. Anyone?

Comment: Are you running the PHP built-in web server on the C9 virtual machine? These typically run locally on a high port, e.g. 10000. Do you want to see this in your own browser, or are you trying to view it inside the C9 virtual environment?

Comment: (More detail required IMO. Bear in mind that short questions of this kind tend to get closed, due to their being perceived as unclear).

Answer (score 4):

I'm the Cloud9 developer who wrote our Xdebug integration. Let me give this a shot:

When you run a local server on your workspace, there's a tunnel on `https://<project-name>-<username>.c9.io/` from where you can access your app in the browser. The local server needs to run on port `8080` for that to work, but better use the `$PORT` env var. If you use the built-in runners, that should work out of the box.

Alternatively, choose *Preview* > *Preview Running App*. Or click the *Share* button and the URL is shown in the share dialog.

Usually, there's also a message which pops up in the top-right of the terminal window that shows you the link and is clickable.

Hope that helps.